# How to multiply an integer by a fraction

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, optimization

So my goal here is to have a function whose signature looks like this:

```
template<typename int_t, int_t numerator, int_t denominator>
int_t Multiply(int_t x);
```

The type is an integral type, which is both the type of the one parameter and the return type.

The other two template parameters are the numerator and denominator of a fraction.

The goal of this function is to multiply a number "x" by an arbitrary fraction, which is in the two template values.  In general the answer should be:

```
floor(x*n/d) mod (int_t_max+1)
```

The naive way to do this is to first multiply "x" by the numerator and then divide.

Looking at a specific case lets say that `int_t`=`uint8_t`, "x" is 30 and the numerator and denominator are 119 and 255 respectively.

Taking this naive route fails because (30*119)mod 256 = 242, which divided by 255 and then floored is 0.  The real answer should be 14.

The next step would be to just use a bigger integer size for the intermediate values.  So instead of doing the 30*119 calculation in mod 256 we would do it in mod 65536.  This does work to a certain extent, but it fails when we try to use the maximum integer size in the `Multiply` function.

The next step would be to just use some `BigInt` type to hold the values so that it *can't* overflow.  This also would work, but the whole reason for having the template arguments, is so that this can be extremely fast, and using a `BigInt` would probably defeat that purpose.

So here is the question:

Is there an algorithm that only involves shifts, multiplication, division, addition, subtraction, and remainder operators, that can preform this mathematical function, without causing overflow issues?

Comment: To answer the question asked here: yes, there is an algorithm that only involves shifts, multiplication, division, addition, subtraction, and remainder operators, that can preform this mathematical function, without causing overflow issues. Oh, as far as what it is, observe that, for example, a 32 bit number can be expressed as a*65536+b, where both `a` and `b` are 16 bit numbers; as such operations on 32 bit numbers can be expressed as equivalent operations on 16 bit numbers, and mathematically combining the results. You'll just have to work out what those operations are, yourself.

Comment: @sam but is it faster than using a bigger int?

Comment: I don't think there's an algorithm that will avoid computing the product with full precision for arbitrary operands.  (If the input and denominator happen to have gcd > 1, you can reduce by this as the initial step.) This means computing full product and then dividing using multiple instances of the narrow type. That will be ugly and always slower than a single hardware multiply and divide at the bigger width. Recommend you re-spec your template to include the type of the intermediate product.

Comment: Since 486DX every Intel CPU comes with a built-in math co-processor. Unless you are failing to list some other requirements (acceptable precision loss, for example) or writing a code for an extremely critical section I have some doubts as to whether this really needs to be optimized the way you describe it

Comment: Assuming the inputs are 8 bit values and that the math is done in 16 bit, then why is the max_int value of 255 an issue? 255*255 = 65025, which will fit in 65536.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows platform I urge you to look into this article on [large integers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383711(v=vs.85).aspx) that currently includes support for up to 128-bit integer values. You can specialize your template based on the bit-with of your `int_t` to serve as a proxy to those OS functions.

Implementing the "shift-and-add" for multiplication *may* provide a good enough alternative but a division will certainly negate any performance gains you could hope for.

Then there are "shortcuts" like trying to see if the `numerator` and `denominator` can be simplified by fraction reduction, e.g. multiplying by 35/49 is the same as multiplying by 5/7.

Another alternative that comes to mind is to "gradually" multiply by "fractions". This one will need some explanation though:

Suppose you are multiplying by `1234567/89012`. I'll use decimal notation for readbility but the same is applicable (naturally) to binary math.

So what we have is a value `x` that needs to be multiplied by that fraction. Since we are dealing with integer arithmetic let's repackage that fraction a bit:

```
1234567/89012 = A + B/10 + C/100 + D/1000...
 = 1157156/89012 + ((71210*10)/89012)/10 + ((5341*100)/89012)/100 + ((801*1000)/89012)/1000...
 = 13 + 8/10 + 6/100 + 9/1000...
```

In fact at this point your main question is "how precise do I want to be in my calculations?". And based on the answer to that question you will have the appropriate number of the members of that long sequence.

That will give you the desired precision and provide a generic "no overflow" method for computing the product, but at what computational cost?